# How to close Terminal and NERDTree windows if they are the last windows?

Tags: autocmd, terminal-buffer, events

If I close all buffers, I'm left with the terminal window, which automatically opens whenever I open Vim.

I would like it close automatically when I exit Vim.

I see that on the NERDTree repo, they included a code that will automatically close NERDTree if it is the last window:

```
" Exit Vim if NERDTree is the only window remaining in the only tab.
autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif
```

I want similarly that: if the terminal window is the last window, Vim close it automatically.

Edit:
If the terminal window **and NERDTree** are the last windows, I want them both to close automatically.

Because I do not want to quit them manually every time I finish editing. In addition, I have the following code for NERDTree in my vimrc:

```
" Exit Vim if NERDTree is the only window remaining in the only tab.
autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif

" Close the tab if NERDTree is the only window remaining in it.
autocmd BufEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Have you tried adapting the code you posted and run into some issue? Or are you not sure how to adapt it?

Comment: Could you tell us what is your Operating System (Windows, Linux)? On Windows to close Vim I believe we have to exit the terminal and not only close the corresponding buffer.

Comment: I use vim on MacOS, Vivian De Smedt.

Comment: Is the solution proposed solving your problem? How can we help you more?

Comment: I have NERDTree as well, so by default NERDTree and the terminal open. Because I have NERDTree as well, I want them to close automatically when there are no more editors.

Comment: I did edit my question, so you can reference the edit. I bountifully appreciate your answer, which I would mark as an answer if it solves my problem, and possibly being that not stating it clearly in the title concerns; I might as well change the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll investigate tonight. I'm sure their is a solution to that problem ;-)

Comment: I have posted a more complex solution that seems to work fine for me. Since it is rather complex I have left the simple solution for the sake of documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more sophisticated solution.

It try to close Vim if the only visible windows are 'side bars' (buffer that don't contains 'real' document) like:

- Terminal
- QuickFix window
- LocationList window
- Help window
- NERDTree side bar
- UndoTree side bar
- Read Only buffers

```
function! IsSideBar(buf_nr)
  " Returns 1 if the buffer is actual a side bar
  " - A terminal
  " - The NERDTree side bar
  " - The QuickFix window
  " - The Help window
  " - The UndoTree side bar
  " - ...
  let buf_name = bufname(a:buf_nr)
  let buf_type = getbufvar(a:buf_nr, '&filetype')
  let readonly = getbufvar(a:buf_nr, '&readonly')

  let term_buffers = term_list()

  if readonly
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'qf'
    " QuickFix, LocationList:
    " Not Read Only
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'help'
    " Read Only
    " Help Window:
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'undotree'
    " Not Read Only
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'nerdtree'
    " Read Only
    return 1

  elseif index(term_buffers, a:buf_nr) >= 0
    return 1

  else
    return 0

  endif
endfunction

function! GetNumWindows()
  " Returns the number of window that are not side bars
  let num_windows = 0
  for win_nr in range(1, winnr('$'))
    let buf_nr = winbufnr(win_nr)

    if IsSideBar(buf_nr)
      continue
    endif

    let num_windows = num_windows + 1
  endfor

  return num_windows
endfunction

function! KillSideBars()
  let num_windows = GetNumWindows()
  if num_windows > 0
    " If there are some non side bar windows do nothing:
    return
  endif

  " Delete the terminal buffers that don't correspond to a window
  let term_buffers = term_list()
  for buf_nr in term_buffers
    if len(win_findbuf(buf_nr)) == 0
      " Exit terminal not associated to a window
      execute 'bd! ' . buf_nr
    endif
  endfor

  let term_buffers = term_list()
  let buf_nr = bufnr('%')
  if index(term_buffers, buf_nr) >= 0
    " Kill the terminal buffer and quit
    call feedkeys("\<C-w>:bd!\<CR>:quit\<CR>:\<BS>")
  else
    " Kill the side bar window
    call feedkeys(":quit\<CR>:\<BS>")
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call KillSideBars()
```

Comment: Thanks! It does my thing, but sometimes it delays my exit with an error `Error detected while processing BufEnter Autocommands for "*":`.

Comment: Does it prompt you? Can you reproduce the problem with a minimal .vimrc file.

Comment: It automatically tells me this and then disappears about half a second later

Comment: Here is my .vimrc, at least the significant parts to it:

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy, I'm willing to help you but I need to reproduce the problem. If you could give a minimal Vim configuration and instruction to reproduce the problem I could have a look. But with just the description of the symptom I can't reproduce it and it is difficult for me to solve it.

Comment: `autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | if argc() > 0 || exists("s:std_in") | wincmd p | endif

autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif

autocmd BufEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | quit | endif`

Comment: This one works for me! The [one below](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/40072/48766) (tried first 'cos it's shorter) does **not** work for me. `vim --version` ==> `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)
Included patches: 1-2434`, Debian bullseye.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && &buftype ==# 'terminal' | bd! | q | endif
```

Compare to the NerdTree solution we do:

- Check that the last buffer is a terminal buffer (`&buftype ==# 'terminal'`)
- Force to delete that buffer even it has been modified (`bd!`)